# Is それで parsed by Japanese speakers as its own unique word, or それ + で?

Tags: meaning

According to my dictionary, the word

> それで

means

> and; thereupon; because of that

while

> それ

means

> that (indicating an item or person near the listener, the action of the listener, or something on their mind)

**Question:** Is それで parsed by Japanese speakers as its own distinct word having nothing to do with それ, or is it seen as the combination それ + で?  I ask because if I squint my eyes and interpret

> それで

as "through (で) that (それ)", it kind of resembles "because of that" (the definition provided above for それで).

Comment: It can be contracted to そんで or, in some dialects, そいで.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's technically two words, それ ("that") + で ("with ～"), but it's treated almost as a one fixed word meaning "So..." or "And...".

それで is sometimes used even at the very beginning of a conversation (English "so" happens to be used like this, too), so the literal meaning of それ is often not important when people say それで.